# Kivy: TextInput border radius

Tags: kivy, textinput

I would like to know if it was possible in python & Kivy, to customize TextInput widgets like in HTML/CSS. Is there any way to do that directly into my `CustomTextInput(TextInput)` class ?

I want my TextInput looks like this:

[image: what I want to obtain]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course you can, but it's a bit more complicated in kivy:

**test.kv**:

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<MyTextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: '14dp'
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    cursor_color: C('#ffffff')
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: C('#ffffff')
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: C('#0f192e')
        Ellipse:
            angle_start:180
            angle_end:360
            pos:(self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1])
            size: (self.size[1], self.size[1])
        Ellipse:
            angle_start:360
            angle_end:540
            pos: (self.size[0] + self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1])
            size: (self.size[1], self.size[1])
        Color:
            rgba: C('#3f92db')
        Line:
            points: self.pos[0] , self.pos[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1]
        Line:
            points: self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1]
        Line:
            ellipse: self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1], self.size[1], self.size[1], 180, 360
        Line:
            ellipse: self.size[0] + self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1], self.size[1], self.size[1], 360, 540

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 20
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: C('#3f92db')
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 80
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: C('#18294a')
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 10
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 20
            orientation:'vertical'
            Label:
                size_hint_y: 8
                text: 'Password'
                color: C('#ffffff')
                font_size:'20dp'
                padding: 5,5
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'center'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: 8
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 25
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 50
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: C('#0f192e')
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    MyTextInput:
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 25
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 10
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 20
            orientation:'vertical'
            Label:
                size_hint_y: 8
                text: 'Confirm'
                color: C('#ffffff')
                font_size:'20dp'
                padding: 5,5
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'center'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: 8
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 25
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 50
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: C('#0f192e')
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    MyTextInput:
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 25
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 40
```

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App


class TestApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you, you are a genius <3 I will try it later and ask you if I have some questions

Comment: Unfortunately this places ellipses outside of the normal bounds of the input text, making the component grow outside of the text input width. This makes it really hard to left-align the text component with other components.