# Canvas Elements in Custom Widget not showing

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I was trying to recreate the rounded `textinput` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47641604/13999352) as a Python class, but the canvas elements are not showing. Instead I get a `TextInput`, where only the cursor and the text are visible.
This is my class:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class RoundedTextInput(TextInput):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.multiline = False
        
        self.background_color = 0,0,0,0
        self.cursor_color = 0,0,0,1
        
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(rgba=(0,0,0,1))
            
        with self.canvas.after:
            Color(rgba=(0,0,1,1))
            self.border_left = Ellipse(
                ange_start=180,
                angle_end=360,
                pos=(self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1]),
                size=(self.size[1], self.size[1]),
                width=5
            )
            self.border_right = Ellipse(
                angle_start=360,
                angle_end=540,
                pos=(self.size[0] + self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1]),
                size=(self.size[1], self.size[1]),
                width=5
            )
            Color(rgba=(0,1,0,1))
            self.line0 = Line(
                points=(self.pos[0] , self.pos[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1]),
                width=5
            )
            self.line1 = Line(
                points=(self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1]),
                width=5
            )
            self.line2 = Line(
                ellipse=(self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1], self.size[1], self.size[1], 180, 360),
                width=5
            )
            self.line3 = Line(
                ellipse=(self.size[0] + self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1], self.size[1], self.size[1], 360, 540),
                width=5
            )
        pass
```

Does anybody see the error?

By the way, I also copied the exact answer code into a separate project with the `.py` and `.kv` file and the result was a blank window.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. However you can check [**`KivyMD`**](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/textfield/#round-mode) which comes with a collection of rich set of ready-to-use widgets.

Comment: Note that the answer you linked uses `kv` language for the canvas drawing. Using `kv` means that the canvas drawing will be automatically updated when the `RoundedTextInput` changes. When you try to do the same in python, you must also create bindings to update the canvas when the `RoundedTextInput` changes. In your code, the canvas elements will be drawn based on the default `pos` (0,0) and the default size `(100,100)`, and will not change when the actual `pos` and `size` of the `RoundedTextInput` are set/changed.